# Paypal Payflow Hosted Checkout page

Tags: php, paypal, payflowpro, payflowlink

I'm trying to integrate Hosted Checkout page on our payment page. I can correctly get a secure token. When I can't redirect the customer to the Hosted Checkout Page.
Via iframe:

```
<iframe id="payflow-link-iframe" sandbox="allow-top-navigation allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-modals" src="https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com/?SECURETOKEN=<?php echo $secureToken; ?>&SECURETOKENID=<?php echo $secureTokenId; ?>"></iframe>
```

I get:  Error: PayPal Express Checkout is not setup on this account.

Via Form:

```
<form id='PPFrom' method='post' action='https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com'>

      <input type='text' name='SECURETOKEN' value="<?php echo $secureToken; ?>">
      <input type='text' name='SECURETOKENID' value="<?php echo $secureTokenId; ?>">
      <input type='text' name='VENDOR' value="<?php echo $vendor; ?>">
      <input type='text' name='PARTNER' value="PayPal">
      <input type='text' name='USER' value="<?php echo $user; ?>">
      <input type='text' name='PWD' value="<?php echo $pw; ?>">
      <input type='text' name='TRXTYPE' value="A">
      <input type='text' name='TENDER'  value="P">
      <input type='text' name='PARMLIST' value="AMT[5]=73.95&INVNUM[5]=123456&ORDERID[5]=123456&ZIP[0]=&STREET[0]=">
      <button type='submit'>Pay</button>
```

On Submit, I get:  RESULT=25&PNREF=A3P02F9E35F0&RESPMSG=Not signed up for this tender type

If I understand well, the SecureToken and SecureTokenID should be enough for opening the Hosted Checkout Page configured in PayPal manager, as all data is sent when requesting the Secure Token. But why it wants to display Express Checkout, not a Hosted Checkout page? What is the connection between these two?
What does the "Not signed up for this tender type" means? 
Which is the best way to display Hosted Checkout page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express checkout is part of the hosted page you are trying to display.  In the "Set Up" configuration page of hosted checkout pages, try entering the PayPal Sandbox Email address of a sandbox business account, from https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F

Your other options are to try disabling EC on that page, or to contact Payflow's support and ask them for help correctly configuring this tender type.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have EC configuration on the Set Up area, so I'm contacting Paypal.

How can I disable EC? Remove the Sandbox configurations?

Answer (score 0):

remove line : 
because [TENDER = P] means calling Pay With PayPal instead of Pay With Credit Card.
Just remove the line and that will do the job!